# How to use "OR" in route parameter?

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing

I'm building a twitter-ish website and I'm having a problem with routing:

1. this code will bring the user to the profile page of the person with the given **id**.

`Route::get('/profile/{id}', 'ProfileController@show')->name('profile.show');`

2. this code will bring the user to the profile page of the person with the given **username**.

`Route::get('/profile/{username}', 'ProfileController@show')->name('profile.show');`

3. and finally, this code will bring the user to the profile page of the person with the given **email**.

`Route::get('/profile/{email}', 'ProfileController@show')->name('profile.show');`

I mean all these three URLs will show the user the same page:

`example.com/profile/1
example.com/profile/rahimi0151
example.com/profile/rahimi0151@gmail.com`

***my question is:***
is there a way to merge all these routes? like below:

`Route::get('/profile/{id|username|email}', 'ProfileController@show')->name('profile.show');`

Answer (score 1):

Am not sure about merging the routes but you could write your route like this

```
Route::get('/profile/{identifier}', 'ProfileController@show')->name('profile.show');
```

and then change the method signature for `show` in `ProfileController` to something like this

```
public function show($identifier) {
    if (is_numeric($identifier)) {
        // do something
    } else if ($this->isEmail($identifier)) {
        // do something
    } else {
        // assume it is a username, and do something with that
    }
}

// method to check if value provided is an email
// preferably, move this to a file of your custom helper functions
private function isEmail($value) {
    // check if value is an email 
    // and return true/false indicating whether value is an email
}
```

And here is a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1725907/check-if-a-string-is-an-email-address-in-php#1725944) for a good way on how to check if a value is valid email address